# RenderScript copy 3D allocation in rs file

Tags: android, renderscript

RenderScript allocations can be 1D, 2D or 3D. Almost all methods support these 3, but the copy method is missing 3D. According to Android developers, below are all data access functions:

```
rsAllocationCopy1DRange Copy consecutive cells between allocations
rsAllocationCopy2DRange Copy a rectangular region of cells between allocations
rsAllocationVLoadX  Get a vector from an allocation of scalars
rsAllocationVStoreX Store a vector into an allocation of scalars
rsGetElementAt  Return a cell from an allocation
rsGetElementAtYuv_uchar_U   Get the U component of an allocation of YUVs
rsGetElementAtYuv_uchar_V   Get the V component of an allocation of YUVs
rsGetElementAtYuv_uchar_Y   Get the Y component of an allocation of YUVs
rsSample    Sample a value from a texture allocation
rsSetElementAt  Set a cell of an allocation
```

As you can see, there is no `rsAllocationCopy3DRange`. I tried it anyway with this code:

```
rsAllocationCopy3DRange(output, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, w, h, d, data, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

And the compile failed.

How to copy 3D allocations? I can write a kernel function just return the input and then `rsForEach` that function, but seems very inefficient for a simple copy.

Why is there no 3D copy? It doesn't make sense. Why is that Java/Kotlin side has 3D copy, but rs side doesn't?

Comment: please add example code of what you want to do

Comment: @AccoGuy I want to copy `data` into `output` where both are 3D allocations. There are 1D and 2D method for this, but not 3D, that is my question, why is there no 3D copy method? If it exists, it should be this line: `rsAllocationCopy3DRange(output, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, w, h, d, data, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);`